# What arguments get passed to the component prop in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I've encountered some code that uses a custom renderer for a `component` in a redux-form based application.  Here's what the `Field` definition looks like:

```
<Field
  name="email"
  component={this.renderInput}
  type="email"
  validate={[email, required]}
/>
```

What I'm interested in is knowing how `renderInput` has access to the following:

```
renderInput({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) {
    return ( ... );
}
```

Where are `input`, `label`, `type` and `meta` coming from? Is this specificed in documentation anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `reduxForm()` function does. It wraps your component inside of another component that passes along all of the props you're already passing in along with the redux form props. This is what is meant by "higher order component".

The documentation is kind of confusing, but the places you want to look what props get passed are the "instance API" sections of these pages: 
[Field](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/field.md/) and [reduxForm](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/reduxform.md/)

Comment: Any chance of explaining how the above is expanded?

Comment: It may just be that I'm really tired at the moment, but I don't quite understand what you mean by how it's expanded.